# Reduce period for web scraping job with puppeter node.js

Tags: node.js, performance, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

I have made a job script for web scraping periodically a page and save some information in a MongoDB database. I have tried to get as much performance as i can, and for now i'm able to execute the script each 10s. However, i would like to reduce it even more, with a period between 1-10 seconds if possible. The problem is that when i reduce it, my code throws the following warning and some executions get stacked unresolved:

```
(node:9472) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

Is there a way to improve the code?

```
const $ = require('cheerio');
const MarketModel = require('./models/marketModel');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
const {
    Cluster
} = require('puppeteer-cluster');


//Connection to DataBase:
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Tradheo', {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', error => console.log(error));
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

getMarketData = async () => {
    console.log("Web scraping to get market data...")

    let markets = []
    let marketSpain = {
        country: 'Spain',
        name: 'IBEX 35',
        companies: []
    }
    let marketGermany = {
        country: 'Germany',
        name: 'DAX',
        companies: []
    }


    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
        concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_PAGE,
        maxConcurrency: 2,
    });

    await cluster.task(async ({
        page,
        data: url
    }) => {
        await page.goto({
            waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'
        });
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on('request', request => {
      if (request.resourceType() === 'document') {
        request.continue();
      } else {
        request.abort();
      }
    });

        const html = await page.content();
        if (url === 'https://uk.investing.com/equities/spain') {
            console.log('Spain data page content loaded');
            $("table[class='genTbl closedTbl crossRatesTbl elpTbl elp30'] > tbody > tr", html).each((i, elem) => {
                marketSpain.companies.push({
                    name: $("td[class='bold left noWrap elp plusIconTd'] > a", html).eq(i).html(),
                    last: $("td", elem).eq(2).text(),
                    high: $("td", elem).eq(3).text(),
                    low: $("td", elem).eq(4).text(),
                    change: $("td", elem).eq(5).text(),
                    changePerCent: $("td", elem).eq(6).text(),
                    volume: $("td", elem).eq(7).text(),
                    time: $("td", elem).eq(8).text(),
                    purchase: false,
                    sale: false
                });
            });
            markets.push(marketSpain);
        } else {
            console.log('Germany data page content loaded');
            $("table[class='genTbl closedTbl crossRatesTbl elpTbl elp30'] > tbody > tr", html).each((i, elem) => {
                marketGermany.companies.push({
                    name: $("td[class='bold left noWrap elp plusIconTd'] > a", html).eq(i).html(),
                    last: $("td", elem).eq(2).text(),
                    high: $("td", elem).eq(3).text(),
                    low: $("td", elem).eq(4).text(),
                    change: $("td", elem).eq(5).text(),
                    changePerCent: $("td", elem).eq(6).text(),
                    volume: $("td", elem).eq(7).text(),
                    time: $("td", elem).eq(8).text(),
                    purchase: false,
                    sale: false
                });
            });
            markets.push(marketGermany);
        }
        if (markets.length === 2) {
            MarketModel.create({
                markets,
            }, (err) => {
                if (err) return handleError(err);
            })

            console.log("Done!")
        }
    });

    cluster.queue(url1);
    cluster.queue(url2);

    await cluster.idle();
    await cluster.close();

}


var j = schedule.scheduleJob('*/10 * 8-17 * * 1-5', function () {
    const now = new Date();
    //Checks that time is between 8:30 - 17:35 (schedule of the stock exchange)
    if (now.getHours() >= 8 && !(now.getHours() == 8 && now.getMinutes() < 30) && now.getHours() <= 17 && !(now.getHours() == 17 && now.getMinutes() > 35)) {
        getMarketData();
    }
});
```

UPDATE: I have added some improvements like setting waitUntil property to 'domcontentloaded' and request interception to avoid waiting for images, and any kind of resources apart from html content, to be loaded. However, seems to be insufficient to achieve the goal.

Comment: Have you considered running multiple instances that are staggered to achieve the same thing?

Comment: @RyanGates Not really, I have just finished my university degree so i have never faced something like this. If you think that's a solution I'm all ears.

Comment: You should ditch puppeteer. It uses an unholy amount of resources and request + cheerio is really all you need.

Comment: @pguardiario I can not use request library because the website i'm scraping uses dynamic content

Comment: The data is right there in the response. I checked.

Comment: I used request library before using puppeteer. The data you are getting depends on the website, in the one i'm scraping the data i got with the request library was the static content, which actually does not coincide with the real content since this dynamic data is append it once the page is loaded. I can check this viewing the difference data between viewing the source code and inspecting it with web browser tools.